# Displaying Twitter Status Ouath

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is probably a stupid question but I cannot find the answer anywhere.

I've got my application connected to twitter (and a few others) via oauth / oauth-plugin.

The token and secret are stored in the db.

My problem is that I have no idea how to display the information, status etc. in my views. Have tried a few things but can't figure it out and don't know what to look for.

thanks in advance, again.

// UPDATE //

I realise now that I need something in my user.rb model to connect. Found this online but don't know how to update for my scenario

```
def twitter
  unless @twitter_user
    provider = self.authentications.find_by_provider('twitter')
    @twitter_user = Twitter::Client.new(:oauth_token => provider.token, :oauth_token_secret => provider.secret) rescue nil
  end
  @twitter_user
end
```

My token and secret are store in consumer_tokens and my provider details are in the oauth initialiser.

Can anyone advise what I should do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i m understanding properly. you want to fecth user's tweet, then here is the solution.

http://rubyonrailshacks.com/how-to-implement-the-simplest-way-to-fetch-friends-timeline-streams-from-twitter-in-ruby-on-rails/

Also if you want to fetch facebook you can must check this:--

http://rubyonrailshacks.com/how-to-fetch-and-show-the-user-stream-from-facebook-via-facebook-connect/

Comment: Hi, those look pretty good but I'm trying to avoid using dedicated plugins because we want to use a number of different services..

Comment: Hi again. On my oauth-plugin index page, I have the following: <% @consumer_tokens.each do |token| %>
     <li>
       <%= link_to token.class.service_name.to_s.humanize, oauth_consumer_path(token.class.service_name) %>
     </li>
   <% end %>    Can't I use something similar?